# Groovy: Poor multithreading performance and slow calculations comparing to Java?

Tags: java, groovy, comparison, performance

According to [an article](http://groovy.dzone.com/news/alex-tkachman-static-groovy) Groovy has

> Unfortunately at the same time Groovy is very slow at runtime. As a person, who did a lot to improve performance of Groovy I can probably speak about that very openly. Groovy is very slow. You can easily expect that some Groovy calculation or data transformation rewritten in Java will become 3-5 times faster. Usually this factor is 8-12 and sometimes even higher. Someone can say that Java is always at our service and nobody uses Groovy for calculations or data processing... But, hey, it is exactly my point - why should we limit ourselves for just scripting or handling of simple web pages?
>
> What is even worse is the fact that
>   Groovy doesn't scale well for
>   multi-core computers meaning that
>   several threads executing code
>   compiled by Groovy really prevent each
>   other from being fast. It is not a
>   problem for many applications but for
>   many others it is simply show-stopper.

Could someone proof or refute that paragraphs?

I am particularly concerned about multi threading performance.

Comment: What kind of "proof" are you looking for?

Comment: Any figures or real-time multiusers projects (e.g. 1k+ concurrent users) based on Groovy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524158/how-popular-is-groovy-grails-in-the-corporate-world might be related

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are ongoing efforts to improve the speed of Groovy, but it should be said that 9 times in 10, the performance is not an issue.

However, where it is an issue you can <s>either</s> write that code in Java (and integrate that Java class easily into your Groovy code), <s>or if you want to remain completely groovy, you can look into using [Groovy++](http://code.google.com/p/groovypptest/) which improves the speed of Groovy by making it more statically typed (with some heavy type inference to save you having to do it all yourself as with Java)</s>

Groovy 1.8b4 (currently in beta), also comes with the [GPars](http://gpars.codehaus.org/) framework bundled with it.

> The GPars project offers developers
> new intuitive and safe ways to handle
> Java or Groovy tasks concurrently,
> asynchronously, and distributed by
> utilizing the power of the Java
> platform and the flexibility of the
> Groovy language.

#### {edit July 2012}

Groovy 2.0 has a CompileStatic annotation which you may want to look into (as now Groovy++ has not been developed for quite a few months).  [This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344412/what-is-the-performance-of-groovy-2-0-with-static-compilation) has some numbers...

Comment: Thank's Tim. I'm aware of Groovy++ (see my original link). What I indeed missing with Groovy++ is an Eclipse support (AFAIK standard Groovy plugins doesn't work with ++ version). Also I'm highly interesting in ++ version because of mentioned static compilation (I big fan of it). And my last point here Groovy++ looks for most people more simpler than Scala and closer to php/VB.

Comment: @FoxyBOA It is a clever project indeed, but yeah, the tooling isn't there yet.  I write processor intensive code (Genetic database analysis), and use groovy for its brevity, readability (and the fact it makes coding fun again), but whenever I need the raw performance, it's so easy to write that bit as pure java and just call the class from Groovy that it seriously doesn't feel like a problem...

Answer (score 6):

> Usually this factor is 8-12 and
>   sometimes even higher. Someone can say
>   that Java is always at our service and
>   nobody uses Groovy for calculations or
>   data processing... But, hey, it is
>   exactly my point - why should we limit
>   ourselves for just scripting or
>   handling of simple web pages?

We don't need to limit ourselves anymore! Groovy 1.8 is out! ;-)

*"**Groovy 1.8.x** prototype for fib(42) takes about 3.8s 
(**only 12% slower than Java, over a hundred times 
faster than Groovy 1.0**) So we may no longer encourage people to write 
such 'hot spots' in Java."*

Source: http://www.wiki.jvmlangsummit.com/images/0/04/Theodorou-Faster-Groovy-1.8.pdf

Now it's Groovy vs. Scala in performance! Please check it out:

*"I'm impressed on how much Groovy's performance has improved for 
numerical computing. **Groovy 1.8** in my project jlab (http://code.google.com/p/jlabgroovy/) 
**sometimes outperforms Scala's performance** in my other project ScalaLab 
(http://code.google.com/p/scalalab) !!"*

Source: http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Great-improvements-in-Groovy-s-performance-for-numerical-computing-td4334768.html

For parallel processing, you can use the already bundled GPars!

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I can only provide anecdotal evidence of poor Groovy performance in calculations (which is, admittedly, about 2 years old):

I implemented an optimization algorithm in Groovy and found it intolerably slow. Profiling it showed that it spent about 60% of its time in `BigDecimal.divide()`. The culprit turned out to be one line with a very simple arithmetic calculation on float values that Groovy somehow insisted on transforming into `BigDecimal`. I tried to avoid having it do that for a bit but failed, so I rewrote that part of the application in Java and saw execution times go down 90%.

Answer (score 2):

"Groovy 1.8.x prototype for fib(42) takes about 3.8s (only 12% slower than Java, over a hundred times faster than Groovy 1.0) So we may no longer encourage people to write such 'hot spots' in Java."

I have just tried it and it is extremely inaccurate. Groovy 1.8 for fib(42) is ~ 25 times slower than java. In my test java fib(42) takes 2 seconds where 1.8 and 1.7.8 take about 52 seconds to complete.

Groovy is still slow ....